# How to overwrite page unload event javascript with custom dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, onbeforeunload, confirm

How to overwrite page onunload event in javascript witha custom dialog ? Please suggest.

This question has been asked many times but I was unable to find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this `<body onunload="myFunction()">` in your html file, and put your custom stuff into the myFunction. You can do many cool things like this, a list can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp).